# ORM проблемы с удалением данных из связаной таблицы

Tags: orm, php, kohana

Есть 3 таблици:categories, products, products_categories. При добавлении товара добавляется запись в таблицу products_categories (product_id, categories_id).

Модель Product выглядит следующим образом:

```
protected $_has_many = array(
    'categories' => array(
        'model' => 'categorie',
        'foreign_key' => 'product_id',
        'through' => 'products_categories',
        'far_key' => 'categories_id',
    ),

);
```

Удаления продукта происходит следующим образом:

public function action_delete(){
        $id = (int) $this->request->param('id');
        if(!$id){
            HTTP::redirect('admin/products/index');
        }

```
    if($this->request->post()){
        $del = Arr::extract($_POST,array('del'));
        if($del['del'] == "Да"){
            $products = ORM::factory('product',$id)->delete(); //Удаляем товар из таблици товаров
            $products->remove('categories',$id); // По идеи должно удалить из таблицы связи. 
        }
        HTTP::redirect('admin/products/index');
    }
}
```

Товар удаляется из таблицы товаров, но возникает проблема как удалить связь товара и категории в таблице products_categories.

Answer (score 2):

То, что вы написали должно удалить связь с категорией, у которой `id = $id`, но не удалит, т.к. в этот момент `$products` уже пуст (`delete()` то вы вызываете до этого).

Чтобы удалить товар со всех категорий, сделайте:

```
$products->remove('categories'); // к слову, почему productS?
```

И только после этого удаляйте продукт:

```
$products->delete();
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает как Вы написали.